# How do you say "Asian fast food restaurant using Chinese frying pan" in English?

Tags: word-request, food

How do you say "Asian fast food restaurant using Chinese frying pan" in English?

It is a kind of restaurant where you can eat cheap food from frying pan, prepared in front of you.

The Polish word for this is "chińczyk".

Comment: It's generally called "stir fry".

Comment: In English, you don't say "Asian fast food restaurant from frying pan"; do you mean "Asian fast food restaurant using frying pans"? I am not sure there is a two-word phrase to say that in English.

Comment: Sure my mistake with "from" :)

Comment: It appears that "chińczyk" in Polish is very similiar to  
"čínský" in Czech, which is a term for anything (not just food) that is Chinese. The most general term I can think of for Chinese food cooked in a wok is "stir-fry".

Comment: Does it literally mean "Chinese person" in Polish? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chińczyk

Comment: @user2307487 It seems so; I translated that Polish word  with Google Translate and it translates it as _Chinese_, _Chinaman_, and _Chink_.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm Yes and not - Does it literally mean "Chinese person"? In Polish = "Polak", Chinese = "Chińczyk" but adjectives Polish = "polski/polska/polskie". In this case "chińczyk" is noun and it is not relate to "Chińczyk" noun apart same sound/write. "chińczyk" is quick food restaurant (it is good food - i.e. small pieces meat mixed with vegetables in five flavors). http://goo.gl/bdxYA http://goo.gl/4A7q9 http://goo.gl/5UMMP luxury version http://goo.gl/XmdBL

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_barbecue.  This is often done directly in front of customers (at least in North America).  I would guess that here seeing something grilled in front of you is more common than seeing something fried in a pan in front of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "Chinese frying pan" is called a *wok*. (I have no idea whether that is an actual word in any dialect of Chinese or an Anglicism.) It is a well known term in the US today, and is very frequently used in the names of restaurants providing East Asian cuisine, especially Chinese cuisine.

In the first half of the last century you frequently encountered *Chop suey joints*, but the (vaguely) Chinese dishes which were then popular - *chop suey*, *chow mein*, *St. Paul sandwich* - are relatively rare now, and the expression is now little used.

Bill Franke's *stir fry* is widely used, but I've never seen it applied to the establishment - you'd have to say *stir fry joint* or *stir fry place* or something of the sort.

If the Polish expression is purely colloquial, I'd say your best bet for translating it would be *Chinese carryout* - or, as appropriate, *Thai carryout* or *Indonesian carryout* or whatever. These may be applied to either the cuisine or the establishment providing it.

If the *wok* is an integral part of the Polish expression, you're going to have to resort to coining a new term. I'd suggest *wokery*, which I think would be understood.

Comment: Yes, it is "Chinese frying pan" = "wok". I think that "carryout" has some potential. We use "chińczyk" for "Vietnamese carryout" what is invalid since it is not Chinese (directly "chińczyk") whatever it is very often use. Wok is used in Polish "wok" but not integral part of "chińczyk" == "Chinese".

Comment: @Chameleon In English, too, *Chinese carryout* has a generic sense; but I think that's mostly because it is only very recently that non-Chinese East Asian cuisine has become generally available in the US. A variety of Chinese cuisines have been available here since at least the 60s, but **not** in fast-food joints, where the menu is very stereotyped.

Comment: BTW Not sure about carryout (since it is not takeaway - you could eat it on site).

Comment: @Chameleon You can eat onsite at most "carryouts", too - there are usually four to eight tables - but few people do. "Cheap" and "fast" are not really compatible with the fine dining experience. But they **are** compatible with "good"!

Comment: Thanks for help and clarification. I will avoid fast. In Poland "cheap" has better relation to "good" that is why I am used it.

Comment: Note that "carryout" is very much American English - in the UK at least it would be called a "takeaway".

Answer (score 1):

In UK English, especially casual use, we just say "a chinese" Eg "I can't be bothered to cook tonight, I'm just going to get a chinese instead." More formally a "chinese restaurant" or "chinese takeaway" - the latter can be used for the building or the food. Some takeaways include some seating, and many restaurants offer a takeaway service, so the categories do overlap.

The use of "chinese" is not common in US English - there was some shock in the US when a UK comedy programme included the expression "I could murder a chinese" meaning "I could eat a lot of chinese food very quickly" was misunderstood and taken literally.

"Chinese carryout", while easy for a UK speaker to understand, is not a common expression in UK English.

Comment: "Carryout" (AmE) = "takeaway" (BrE)